# Back press event of titanium

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I am trying to handle the back press event of android in titanium using appcelerator. But when user presses back the app gets closed in android. Can any one tell me the solution.

```
exitOnClose= false ;

 $.index.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    // write your code here
    Ti.API.info('android back pressed');
    return;
});
```

I have added this code as per the suggestions but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the event and do nothing

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.addEventListener('androidback',function(event){
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      return false;
}
```

Also use the `exitOnClose` property: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-exitOnClose

Comment: Be careful with Ti.UI.currentWindow, it will work only if there is a window opened, so to add this listener you will need to listen also to open: isn't it better to place androidback directly on the controller then?

Comment: can you please tell me how to write android back directly on the controller? @RenePot

Comment: `$.getView().addEventListener('androidback',function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

It might be happing if you pressing back on the first window like in alloy `index`, it will close the app. But if you do not want to close the app on pressing android back just override the `androidback` lister of the window and write your code in it.

```
$.index.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    // write your code here
    Ti.API.info('android back pressed');
    return;
});
```

also you can look for more in the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-androidback).

Comment: I have added your code in one of my controller's js file. Its giving me Uncaught TypeError Can not call method 'addEventListener' of undefined @Swanand

Comment: @D.Devkar Can you share some of your code, that would be more helpful.

Comment: I have added the code in to my question please check. I have written this code in one of my controller's js file

Comment: The code samples assume you are in the index controller or used the id-attribute on the root-level element to set it to `index`. If you use a different controller or ID, update the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Alloy>
    <Window onAndroidback="doAndroidBack">
        <View class="container">
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>



//Orverrride back function with empty function
function doAndroidBack(){}
```